# Printing all Excel files in a folder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, printing

I have a PowerShell script that I wrote a few years ago and it worked great...until it didn't.

```
$shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application 
$filepath = 'C:\Billing\Clients' 

$shell.Namespace($filepath).Items() | 
% { $_.InvokeVerb('Print') }
```

In the C:\Billing\Clients folder I copy ~100 Excel files. Each of these Excel files need to be printed, in the alphabetical order of the file name.

This was working great until this month. I guess an update to Excel changed things.

Now the script tries to open and print all of the Excel files at the same time. Previously it printed the files in serial.

This was awesome. Now it brings my system to it's knees and documents are printed in a random order.

Any ideas on how I can invoke the Print operation and wait for it to complete prior to calling the Print operation on the next file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this in the past to pull files into excel and print them. You will need to ensure your default print settings are set first or use `$xl.ActivePrinter = "PRINTERNAME AS EXCEL SEES IT"` to set it first.

```
#Open Excel
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
#don't show the window
$xl.visible = $false
#get all of your files
get-childitem "C:\SOME\Path" "*.xlsx" | foreach-object {
    #open file
    $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
    #print with defaults
    $wb.PrintOut()
    #close without saving any changes
    $wb.Close($false)
}
#all done so close excel
$xl.Quit()
```

Comment: The only thing that I can't make work is the $xl.ActivePrinter command. I've placed the right after the $xl.visible property, and set the printer name to the name as it's listed in Excel, with no success. It works great if I set the default printer in Control Panel manually.

Comment: Got the printer to work. the $xl.ActivePrinter command goes right before the $wb.PrintOut. To get the printer name, open a Powershell window and run the following with the printer set as the default in Control Panel to get the right name: 
$xl = New-Object -comobject excel.application
$xl.ActivePrinter
This will print out the print name that can be copied and used in the script.